# When Luffy goes under the name "Lucy" in the colliseum is this a shout out to "Fairy Tail" or is it just a coincidence

Tags: one-piece, fairy-tail

In One Piece, in Season 12, Monkey D. Luffy goes under disguise as "Lucy".

I wondered if this was a shout out to Fairy Tail from the author of One Piece.  Does anyone know?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it most probably is not! The authors have worked together in an adaption or two(Not sure, read it somewhere) but that's it, they aren't that close to enough, to add an entire arc referring to Fairy Tail.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's a possibility, and I recall reading an article without sources which claims this to be the case, based on the fact that the two authors worked together in some crossovers.

If you're interested in exploring a false dichotomy, I've also read an opinion on Reddit that this instance of "Lucy/Rushi" should not be a reference to *Fairy Tail*, but rather to Muten Roshi from *Dragon Ball*. I have my reasons to believe that said opinion relies chiefly on poor understanding of Japanese and personal aversion to *Fairy Tail* by the person who posted it. For disclosure, I don't know Japanese. As I said, though, refuting this hypothesis would have no bearing on yours.